# How to pass variable from Guzzle Request In Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm trying to pass a variable from guzzle request to my view.

**This is my controller**

```
  $client = new Client();
  $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.iugu.com/v1/customers?api_token=secret');
  $result = $res->getBody();
  $clientes = json_decode($result, true);
  return view('sections.client.index')->with('clients', $clientes['items']);
```

**But return error:**

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/cron_verify/resources/views/sections/client/index.blade.php)
```

**This is my JSON**

[image]

**And this is my view**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-3-offset table_box">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Faturas</th>
          <th>Situação</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($clients as $value)
        <tr>
          <td>{{$value->name}}</td>
          <td>{{$value->email}}</td>
          <td>{{$value->number}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I dont understand why I am getting this error because the value is in the JSON response. What is causing the error?

Comment: try `dd($clientes)` and show us and try to add full error message with view code

Comment: @Vinicius Rosa please show your html code also

Comment: @Sohel0415 I edited my question.

Comment: @Kirit I edited my question

Comment: please show your view code too

Comment: But I put the code from view too @Sohel0415

Comment: @ViniciusRosa yeah, i have answered, have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to `access` element as `array` value.

```
@foreach($clients as $value)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$value["name"]}}</td>
      <td>{{$value["email"]}}</td>
      <td>{{$value["number"]}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks a lot @Sohel0415

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you are working with arrays, no with objects. Use this foreach instead.

```
    @foreach($clients as $value)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$value['name']}}</td>
      <td>{{$value['email']}</td>
      <td>{{$value['number']}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

**You are accessing the array wrongly**

**Try:**

```
@foreach($clients as $value)
    <tr>
      <td> {{$value["name"]}} </td>
      <td> {{$value["email"]}} </td>
      <td> {{$value["number"]}} </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

It's happend becasue you are using `$clientes = json_decode($result, true);` returning an associative object, than, on your view you must use this:

```
<tr>
      <td>{{$value['name']}}</td>
      <td>{{$value['email']}}</td>
      <td>{{$value['number']}}</td>
    </tr>
```